# Uncaught Twig Error Loader in Opencart 3.0.3.1

Tags: twig, opencart-3

How to solve this error as I am getting fatal error while performing edit action on module in admin

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig_Error_Loader: Unable to find template
>   "extension/module/linkedin_logintwig.twig" (looked into:
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/admin/view/template). in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php:215
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php(139):
>   Twig_Loader_Filesystem->findTemplate('extension/modul...') #1
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(312):
>   Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey('extension/modul...') #2
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/system/library/template/Twig/Environment.php(378):
>   Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass('extension/modul...', NULL) #3
>   /opt/lampp/storage/modification/system/library/template/twig.php(42):
>   Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('extension/modul...') #4
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/system/library/template.php(51):
>   Template\Twig->render('extension/modul...', '1') #5
>   /opt/lampp/storage/modification/system/engine/loader.php(125):
>   Template->render('extension/m in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/eCommerce/system/library/template/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
>   on line 215

Comment: ensure does this file `extension/module/linkedin_logintwig.twig` exist...

Comment: Could be a problem with a LinkedIn extension you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for help. I solved this error, its a syntax error due to which I am getting.

Error was in below line which I made it correct

`$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/linkedin_login', $data));`